# Relative coordinates in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, coordinates

Ti*k*Z gives us the ease of using relative coordinates, like in the following example.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (-1,0);
    \draw[blue,->] (A) -- +(30:1);
    \draw[red] ($(A)+(30:1)$) +(30+90:1) -- +(30-90:1) -- +(30:0.5) -- +(30+90:1) coordinate (end);
    \draw[green] (A) -- (end) ++(30-90:2) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: ex]

This is extremely elegant, as I do not have to computed the coordinates by hand, especially when using arbitrarily placed nodes.

As PSTricks makes use of the computational power of Postscript, I hope there is a way to use relative coordinates. The syntax might not be as easy as in Ti*k*Z, but using 3D and plotting is much easier with PSTricks.

**Question:** Does PSTricks have capabilities for relative coordinates? (If yes, how do I use them?)

Comment: give another example, because the above is a simple `\psline(1,0)`

Comment: I adjusted my post. Of course `\psline(1,0)` would have worked in that case, but needs the explicit coordinate `(1,0)`.

Comment: What do you think about my answer, are  you satisfied with it? If no, please explain what kind of answer you are seeking.

Comment: I added more excessive examples. My question is about all the mechanisms, that exist for handling relative coordinates in PSTricks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\psrline` is explained in `pst-node` documentation on page 41 but its code is implemented in `pstricks-add`. As usual, there might be a historical reason for this.

### Based on your first case (before editing):

`\psrline(A)(B)(C)...` is equivalent to `\draw (A) -- ++(B) -- ++(C)...`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-2,-1)(1,1)
    \pnode(-1,0){A}
    \psrline(A)(1;30)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Based on your second case (after editing):

As far as I know, there is no PSTricks equivalent for `\draw (A) -- +(B) -- +(C)...`. The following code produces the same output as yours.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=true](-2,-1)(1,2)
    \pnode(-1,0){A}
    \pnode([nodesep=1,angle=30]A){B}
    \pnode([nodesep=1,angle={!30 90 add}]B){end}
    \psrline[linecolor=blue]{->}(A)(1;30)
    \psline[linecolor=red](B)(end)([nodesep=1,angle={!30 90 sub}]B)([nodesep=0.5,angle=30]B)(end)
    \psline[linecolor=green](A)(end)
    \psline[linecolor=green]([nodesep=2,angle={!30 90 sub}]end)(A)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for adjusting your answer. Now it covers a broader range.

Comment: I will make use of all the things explained in your answer to typeset the graphics for lecture notes. Hopefully, I encounter new practices and can extend this answer with more examples.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

 \begin{pspicture}[showgrid](9,10)
 \psStartPoint(1,0)
 \psVector(1;30) 
 \psStartPoint(1,1)
 \psVector[arrows=-](3;30)
 \psVector[arrows=-](4;60)
 \psVector[linecolor=red,arrows=-](3;10)
 \psVector[linestyle=dashed,arrows=-](4;110)
 \end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

another possibility for a single line segment is `\rput(-1,0){\psline(1;30)}`

Comment: `\psrline` is explained in `pst-node` documentation but its code is defined in `pstricks-add`. Do you know it?